# Failing to Edit only what is necessary

Tags: support, edits

I need to edit my own question ([Could not include codeigniter controller files in external php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652617/could-not-include-codeigniter-controller-files-in-external-php-script)) but it doesn't allow me to edit. It displays "you need to edit at least 6 characters" or message like that. but I should edit only where the error appears. Isn't it?

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: @DeerHunter yes in both.

Comment: Can you link the question?

Comment: < a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652617/could-not-include-codeigniter-controller-files-in-external-php-script?noredirect=1#comment57052826_34652617">This is the question</a>  and i somehow edited already deleting the text and rewriting it. @PatrickHofman

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you created (or was trying to edit) the question on another account (possibly even a guest session account).

That will bring the same restrictions as other users have when editing someone else's post.

If the above is true, the best thing you can do is ask to merge your two accounts. You can do that using the *Contact Us* link on the bottom of this page.